Calculating the corners of a rotated outer rectangle that encapsulates minimally an inner rectangle.
I have two rectangles that start as the same size. When I rotate one of these rectangles I want it to encapsulate the other rectangle taking up the minimum possible area. The coordinates of the corners of the inner rectangle are known, as well as the angle the outer rectangle will be rotated by. Only the outer rectangle will be rotated. Also while the rotation will be made around the outer and inner rectangle's center that center is not guaranteed to be at the origin.
Rotated Coordinate Planes
My current idea is like in the picture to rotate the coordinate plane by the angle of the rotation and then form lines from the corners of the inner rectangle parallel to the x and and y axis of the rotated coordinate plane. Then find the intersection points of these lines and the four intersections I believe should be the corners of the outer rectangle. However I don't know how to find the functions of these lines based on the original coordinate plane, nor if this is the simplest solution.

Would you explain us your ideas?

@Cesareo My current idea is to rotate the coordinate plane by the angle of the rotation and then form lines from the corners of the inner rectangle along the x and and y axis of the rotated coordinate plane. Then find the intersection points of these lines and the four intersections I believe should be the corners of the outer rectangle. However I don't know how to find the functions of these lines based on the original coordinate plane.

Do you want to find corners of the outer rotating rectangle?

@Narasimham Yes

HINT:
Construct semi-circles on each side of the inner rectangle. Use Thale's theorem to draw outer rotating rectangle continuous sides. No harm taking inner rectangle center as the origin.
Roughly sketched what I meant. Outer rectangle has its corner labels primed. Per EOQ policy afraid cannot  hint further.

